# How to interpolate data of mnist digits set?

Tags: python, tensorflow, scipy, mnist

I want to reshape the MNIST digits dataset from (28, 28) to (32, 32). One way is to interpolate the data. I use custom Radial Basis Function for interpolation. How to do it??

Here is the RBF function

```
def RBF(x, c, s):
return np.exp(-np.sum((x-c)**2, axis=1)/(2*s**2))
```

where x is the actual value, c is the centre(assumed as mean) and s is standard deviation.

Here is how I load the data from tensorflow

```
import tensorflow as tf
data = tf.contrib.learn.datasets.mnist.load_mnist()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use, `tf.image.resize_with_pad` which resizes the image to a target width and height by keeping the aspect ration the same without distortion.

Below is the code for the same.

```
import tensorflow as tf
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) =tf.keras.datasets.mnist.load_data(path='mnist.npz')

original_image = x_train[0].reshape(28,28,1)
resized_image = tf.image.resize_with_pad(original_image, 32,32) 

plt.imshow(original_image.reshape(28,28))
```

**Original Image:**

[image]

**Resized Image:**

```
plt.imshow(resized_image.numpy().reshape(32,32))
```

[image]

You can see the scale range in both the images and the aspect ratio is also maintained.